# Maven eclipse workspace path

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have 1 dependency defined like this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ciutat</groupId>
        <artifactId>ciutat-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>/Users/peris/Development/J2EE/eclipse-workspace/ciutat/target/ciutat-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to define the eclipse-workspace in a variable, like `{eclispe-workspace}`

Comment: Why do you need a dependency defined by system scope?

Comment: Try to avoid systemPath dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is properties tag of maven

add this at top of you pom

```
<properties>
    <eclispe-workspace>/Users/peris/Development/J2EE/eclipse-workspac/<eclispe-workspace>
</properties>
```

and then in your pom , you can use it like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.ciutat</groupId>
        <artifactId>ciutat-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${eclispe-workspace}/ciutat/target/ciutat-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
```

Note -  using system path is not recommendable. System scope will cause problems to you - when you move your application into a different server or system.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use :**

- For Projects Output directory : `${project.build.outputDirectory}`
- For projects test Output Directory : `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}`
- For Source Directory : `${project.build.sourceDirectory}`
- For User’s current working : `${user.dir}`

> **outputDirectory** and **testOutputDirectory** provide access to the
>   directories where Maven is going to put bytecode or other build
>   output.

Comment: @en Peris : try out this solution and let me know if you face any issue